# Spring Boot REST Controller altering field data

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-boot

I'm creating a REST endpoint for a project I am working on. In my Postgresql instance, I have a table with a column of type TEXT. The field is used to store text that is intended to be processed on the frontend as Markdown. For example, the field has text similar to:

`# This is my headline\n\nThis is a paragraph of text\n\n## This is a subhead`

The endpoint in Spring Boot is as follows:

```java
@GetMapping(value = "/nations")
private List<Nation> getAllNations() {
    return nationDAO.getAllNations();
}
```

Now, when I hit the endpoint, I get the data returned from the row, but the TEXT fields look like some kind of processing is occurring on them.

Using the previous example, it gets returned in the JSON as:

```json
[
    {
     "id": 1,
     "myTextField": "# This is my headline\\n\\nThis is a paragraph of text\\n\\n## This is a subhead",
     "population": 123456
    }
]
```

Is there any way to prevent `\n` from being converted to `\\n`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just want to put this here in case anyone runs into this and is confused like I was:

You actually want this behavior. If we keep `\n`, it will break JSON parsing. For example, if you were to parse the `\n` with JavaScript on the frontend, you would get an `Unexpected Token` error.